# How can I proove that a point in the Cartesian plane belongs to the convex hull of a specific polytype in the plane?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

Suppose that we have the set $E=\{(0,0),(1,2),(2,1)\}$ and the points of this set, are the vertices of a triangle. How can I prove that the point $(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{3}{2})$ belongs to the convex hull of the polytype generated by $E$ ?

I think if something can prove this, then it is easy to write it as convex combination of the other points of the set $E$, right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well...Isn't this a standard type of problem?

Comment: @Community is this better?

Comment: You can just write your point as a convex combination of the 4 points to show that it lies in the convex hull

Comment: @TannySieben you mean this ?

$$(3/2,3/2)=(0,0)x_1+(2/3,2/3)x_2+(1,2)x_3+(2,1)x_4$$

Comment: Your point actually lies on the border of the convex hull, midway between (2,1) and (1,2). Presumably there are algorithms for this that are faster than just checking every triplet of vertices in $E$ to see if the point lies in the triangle they form. What algorithm you want will depend on whether $E$ is fixed with many points tested against it, or if $E$ is different every time.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis this $E$ is fixed for this case, but is it difficult someone to prove this in general? Is there some other post in the forum here, that has an expalme that is similar to mine so as I could do the exercise on my own if nobody answers in the quenstion? Thak you in advance!

Comment: For a fixed set $E$ you would use any of the many [convex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) to find the convex hull itself, which in 2d would be a convex polygon. In your example the point (2/3,2/3) would be removed since it is an interior point, leaving just a triangle. Then you can just test any point against that polygon with a [point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm. It is unclear whether you are actually working in 2d or 4d since you call it [4-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-polytope) for some reason.

Comment: ok let me fix this then

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I removed the point (2/3,2/3) and now I have a triangle, so I think it is better now!

Answer (score 0):

For a large number of points $P_i$ and a point $Q$, it is faster check whether $Q$ is separated from the points $P_i$ by a hyperplane ( i.e. not in c. h.) or not ( i.e. in the c. h.).

Consider the linear problem: Maximize $l(Q)$, with the condition $l(P_i) \le 0$, where $l(P) = l(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum a_i x_i + b$  ( so you are looking for $(a_1, \ldots, a_n, b)$ ( add in the condition $l(P) \le 1$ to guarantee a bounded solution).

Comment: @orangekid my understanding based on your answer is zero :P It is not your fault of course...but can you answer based on my example?

Comment: @KingOdysseus: write it as: $(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}) = 0 \cdot (0,0) + \frac{1}{2}(1,2) + \frac{1}{2}(2,1) $, so it is in the convex hull ( you may omit the $0$ coefficient)

Comment: From what I understand, I need to write down the following
$$(3/2,3/2)=(0,0)p_1+(1,2)p_2+(2,1)p_3=(0p_1+p_2+2p_3,0p_1+2p_2+p_3)$$
s.t.
$$p_1+p_2+p_3=1$$
where
$$p1\geq 0,\quad p_2\geq 0,\quad p_3\geq 0$$
and hence $$(p_1,p_2,p_3)=(0,1/2,1/2)$$

Comment: @King Odysseus: yes, you got it!